# Error PLS-00103 in PL/SQL function

Tags: oracle, plsql

This code won't compile. I don't know what's going on. I'm using Oracle 8i

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SALMINS 
IS RETURN NUMBER
   SAL NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
 SELECT MIN(SALARIO) INTO SAL FROM EMPLE;
 RETURN (SAL);
END;
```

Error:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the
         following:
         ( return compress compiled wrapped
```

Table definition:

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMP_NO                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 APELLIDO                                           VARCHAR2(10)
 OFICIO                                             VARCHAR2(10)
 DIR                                                NUMBER(4)
 FECHA_ALT                                          DATE
 SALARIO                                            NUMBER(10)
 COMISION                                           NUMBER(10)
 DEPT_NO                                            NUMBER(2)
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message? It will help us to pin down what's going wrong.

Comment: @Aleksej has the solution, I can't mark him because I'm a novice

Comment: But you can accept Aleksej's answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I've corrected your question - you don't get a "bug", you get a compilation error. The error isn't `return compress compiled wrapped`, those are the valid values the compiler is telling you it was expecting instead where you have `IS`.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SALMINS 
RETURN NUMBER IS   -- and not IS RETURN NUMBER
   SAL NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
 SELECT MIN(SALARIO) INTO SAL FROM EMPLE;
 RETURN (SAL);
END;
```